# Set and concat to string field with arrayFilters in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My MongoDB document looks like this.

```
{
_id: '556ebf103a8b4c3d067bb6466df7c0651c53a1ff79fa348edff656586c24ad0c',
Log: [
    {
        ScriptName: 'UpdateScript',
        ScriptLogs: [
            {
                ID: 'f5bd1fefb2a5c4712ea1d35eb5bd309074984c5932db3723cc29f8d92258a3fa',
                StdOut: 'Hello'
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

I have the MongoDb Query

```
db.getCollection("ServerEntitys").update(

    {_id: '556ebf103a8b4c3d067bb6466df7c0651c53a1ff79fa348edff656586c24ad0c'},
    {
        $set: {
            'Log.$[i].ScriptLogs.$[j].StdOut': { "$concat": ["$Log.$[i].ScriptLogs.$[j].StdOut", "World"]}
        }
    },
    { arrayFilters: [ { "i.ScriptName": "UpdateScript" } , { "j.ID": 'f5bd1fefb2a5c4712ea1d35eb5bd309074984c5932db3723cc29f8d92258a3fa'} ] }
)
```

After running the query I get

```
StdOut: {
            $concat: [
                '$Log.$[i].ScriptLogs.$[j].StdOut',
                'World'
            ]
         },
```

instead of

```
StdOut: 'HelloWorld'
```

Can someone tell me why mongoDB uses $concat as value and not as a $concat instruction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using normal update, you should use ONLY [update operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/)

After MongoDB 4.2, we can also update using a pipeline update, using ONLY aggregate operators (no update ones, no arrayfilters etc)

We dont have an update operator that concat strings, so looks like you need pipeline update like the bellow.

Query

- nested `$map`
- outer to match the `updateScript`
- inner to match the `ID`
- in both cases if no match is found we keep the old array member

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=629e6d9c91b564fc1e7e959a)

```js
coll.updateMany({},
[{"$set": 
   {"Log": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$Log",
        "as": "outer",
        "in": 
         {"$cond": 
           [{"$ne": ["$$outer.ScriptName", "UpdateScript"]}, "$$outer",
             {"$mergeObjects": 
               ["$$outer",
                 {"ScriptLogs": 
                   {"$map": 
                     {"input": "$$outer.ScriptLogs",
                      "as": "inner",
                      "in": 
                       {"$cond": 
                         [{"$ne": ["$$inner.ID", "2"]}, "$$inner",
                           {"$mergeObjects": 
                             ["$$inner",
                               {"StdOut": 
                                 {"$concat": 
                                   ["$$inner.StdOut"," World"]}}]}]}}}}]}]}}}}}])
```

Comment: thank you very much it is working now. I really hoped for a easier and more compact query.